# In MySQL, How to update 2 columns with new values in bulk loaded from a csv (mapped from a primary key)

Tags: sql, mysql

Using MySQL Workbench, I have a master items table, called items_tbl. It has 3 columns: item_no (primary key), food_category (varchar), and promo_type (varchar). We have recently decided to revise all the categories/types in the latter 2 columns, and I have prepared a csv with the item # along with these 2 columns and each new value associated with each item #. How do I write the load statement?

Feels like it should be pretty straight forward, but alas, I cannot find the answer as it relates directly to my situation. Newbie here, i typically only insert new data or UPDATE SET with 1 row at a time.

Comment: Load into temptable then update with common multiple-table UPDATE. Also, if your CSV is correct with guarantee then you may open it directly using `Engine = CSV` in UPDATE, loading into intermediate table not needed in this case, but you'd use according CREATE TABLE instead.

Comment: Why can't you just use `LOAD DATA`? The `REPLACE` option tells it to replace existing rows when there's a duplicate key.